# Emmeans in LME and adjusting for "time since"

Tags: r, na, nlme, emmeans

I would like to reassure myself that what I'm doing is right. I am applying an LME model to my data. And I would like to know if the use of EMMEANS to get multiple comparisons is right.

```
emmeans(mod1.lme, pairwise ~ Status, adjust="bonferroni")
```

The variable 'Status' has 4 factors, and I would like to know how to adjust my LME for 'Time since event' when only 2 of those factors are affected by that event. 
Would be enough to include `na.action = na.omit` at the end of the model or I should do anything else to control for that?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data or explain in more detail what you are analyzing? What is "time since event"?

Comment: Hello! actually I think this question is not very well explained. What I wanted to ask is what I have already asked in this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553218/can-i-use-emmeans-with-lme-model 

Would you be able to help? I'd really appreciate it! 

Thanks!